# in `+': nil can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError) Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Get the following error when testing my method for false test cases shown below, not sure why. Other test cases that result in true work out well. The method takes in an array of integers and returns true if any three consecutive elements sum to 7 and returns false otherwise.

```
def lucky_sevens?(numbers)
      i=0
      while i <= numbers.length
        if (numbers[i] + numbers[i+1] + numbers[i+2]) == 7
            return true
            end
        i+=1
      end
    end
```

puts lucky_sevens?([7,7,7,7,]) == false

puts lucky_sevens?([3,4,3,4]) == false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking up to the last element and then 2 number after it. Accessing an element in array bigger then the length returns `nil`. Trying to add `nil` to a number will produce the error you saw.

To solve it you should stop checking when the last of the 3 elements reaches the end of the array, not the first. Meaning you should stop 2 elements earlier.

It's easily achieved by just subtracting 2 from the length in your loop.

```
def lucky_sevens?(numbers)
  i=0
  while i < numbers.length - 2
    if (numbers[i] + numbers[i+1] + numbers[i+2]) == 7
      return true
    end
    i+=1
  end
  false
end
```

A more ruby way to do this, would be the following:

```
def lucky_sevens?(numbers)
  numbers.each_cons(3).any? do |group_of_3|
    group_of_3.sum == 7
  end
end
```

Comment: So that fixes the issue with nil. The follow-up would be where in the method to return "false" otherwise?

Comment: If it passes the loop and doesn't return true in it, then it should be false. Just add false after the end of the loop. If it ever reaches that line, we know it wasn't true. Updated my anwser.

Comment: This is great! Two follow-up questions: Is there any big difference between using ".any?" vs ".include?"? Also, for both of these, I tried putting "return false" after the loops or simply just "false" but it still doesn't return false for those specific test cases -- it's just blank. How do I get it to explicitly print "false"? Thanks!